# "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER <full path> is not a full path and was not found in the PATH" - when it actually is a full path

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, configuration

I get this error using CMake from Microsofts VSCode extension "CMake Tools"

```
[cmake]   The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe
[cmake] 
[cmake]   is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.
```

But it's quite literally exactly that path containing all the binaries (I've double checked that)! I've selected it using the "CMake: Select a Kit" Dropdown menu (F1 -> CMake: Select a Kit)

I have both MinGW and Cygwin installed on my machine. It also doesn't work for Cygwin:

```
[cmake]   The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     C:/cygwin64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe
[cmake] 
[cmake]   is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.
```

You can see that both paths are actually full paths but they're somehow not accepted by cmake.

One thought I had was that I don't know in what environment cmake is actually executed in if used via the vscode-cmake-tools extension. If it uses the same default terminal as when I spawn a new terminal this would default to the Cygwin terminal which could explain the issue. However, cmake is also found:

`[proc] Executing command: C:/cygwin64/bin/cmake.exe --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -Sc:/dev/supabase-cpp -Bc:/dev/supabase-cpp/build -G "Unix Makefiles"`

So this can hardly be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code inherits its environment variables from the environment it was launched from (as does any program). The problem could be related to where you invoke VS Code from (which has an effect on what environment variables it inherits, such as the PATH variable).

Your problem description seems to match up closely with the one in [this GitHub issue ticket (#1376)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/1376). The issue reporter encountered the problem because they were invoking VS Code from cmd and and not from a cygwin terminal.

[Quoting Bob Brown](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/1376#issuecomment-661145252) (one of the maintainers of the vscode-cmake-tools extension):

> Based on my limited knowledge of cygwin, I believe there is a shell environment that you need to run from in order for your compiler to work. If you did not launch VS Code from this environment, it's possible that your PATH is not set up in a way that your compiler will function properly.

Try running VS Code from your Cygwin terminal and see if that resolves the issue.